# Highcharts Gantt Chart: Not supporting parent child feature on Y axis with categories declaration on YAxis configuration

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gantt-chart

I am using Highcharts Gantt Chart for plotting gantt chart. I am using parent keyword in data for grouping. When I give YAxis configuration with categories, it is not supporting parent-child grouping.

Reference I used: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/gantt/demo/subtasks

Expected same output but with YAxis categories (want to achieve drag and drop feature, for this we need Y axis categories).

Sample Code:

```js
var today = new Date(),
    day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// Set to 00:00:00:000 today
today.setUTCHours(0);
today.setUTCMinutes(0);
today.setUTCSeconds(0);
today.setUTCMilliseconds(0);


// THE CHART
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Gantt With Subtasks'
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: today.getTime() - (2 * day),
        max: today.getTime() + (32 * day)
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        categories: ['Planning', 'Requirements', 'Design']
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Project 1',
        data: [{
            name: 'Planning',
            id: 'planning',
            start: today.getTime(),
            end: today.getTime() + (20 * day),
            y: 0
        }, {
            name: 'Requirements',
            id: 'requirements',
            parent: 'planning',
            start: today.getTime(),
            end: today.getTime() + (5 * day),
            y: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Design',
            id: 'design',
            dependency: 'requirements',
            parent: 'planning',
            start: today.getTime() + (3 * day),
            end: today.getTime() + (20 * day),
            y: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Layout',
            id: 'layout',
            parent: 'design',
            start: today.getTime() + (3 * day),
            end: today.getTime() + (10 * day),
            y: 3
        }, {
            name: 'Graphics',
            parent: 'design',
            dependency: 'layout',
            start: today.getTime() + (10 * day),
            end: today.getTime() + (20 * day),
            y: 4
        }, {
            name: 'Develop',
            id: 'develop',
            start: today.getTime() + (5 * day),
            end: today.getTime() + (30 * day),
            y: 5
        }, {
            name: 'Create unit tests',
            id: 'unit_tests',
            dependency: 'requirements',
            parent: 'develop',
            start: today.getTime() + (5 * day),
            end: today.getTime() + (8 * day),
            y: 6
        }, {
            name: 'Implement',
            id: 'implement',
            dependency: 'unit_tests',
            parent: 'develop',
            start: today.getTime() + (8 * day),
            end: today.getTime() + (30 * day),
            y: 7
        }]
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/highcharts-gantt.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is impossible with the current Gantt implementation. When `yAxis` uses the `categories` received the `type as categories`, meanwhile the toggle option is implemented only for the `type: 'treegrid'`. May I ask why do you want to use the `categories`?

Comment: I want to implement drag and drop feature on gantt chart. I am not able to achieve it without defining categories on YAxis. But if I declare categories on YAxis then parent feature stops working. Can you please suggest me is there any other way to achieve both 'drag and drop' and grouping by parent in one chart?

Comment: I am afraid that the mix of those two functionalities is not implemented yet. The drag works only for the xAxis. See: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z8aybsm9/ You can report this idea about mixing those two features on the Highcharts Github issue channel. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Sebastian. I will report this issue on provided github channel.